# The "is" type pattern expression for null check

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I can refactor this code (popular `as/null check` pattern)

```
var a = b as MyType;
if(a != null) { ... }
```

..into a nice ["is" type pattern expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression):

```
if(b is MyType a) { ... }
```

..which is cool... I think... Is it?

---

But now I am also thinking to refactor

```
var a = SomeMethod();
if(a != null) { ... }
```

..into:

```
if(SomMethod() is MyType a) { ... }
```

Note: there is no `as` and **SomeMethod() already returns MyType**. It looks like (pseudocode) `if(A is A)` and may easily confuse, no?

The first refactoring is legal, but what about the latter one? I am not an IL expert to check myself and C# 7.0 features are still new to me. Perhaps there are problems which I didn't discover yet?

Comment: The second one is legal, and I've seen it recommended by others, but I'm not sure I'm its biggest fan...

Comment: "The first refactoring is legal" Just try it out and see what happens. If you **should** do it, is another question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I just tried your `if (SomeMethod() is var o` variant, but when the returned value is null, it actually returns true? Are you sure, it is semantically the same? Which actually leads me to a followup question: Why is the result different? `if (SomeMethod() is var o)` always yields true, whereas `if (SomeMethod() is object o)` yields false when the returned value is null.

Comment: @ChristophHerold That's the difference between `SomeMethod() is var o` and `SomeMethod() is MyType a` -- `var` matches null, but `MyType` doesn't.

Comment: But why? var is interpreted as object in that case? Anyways, I'm just writing up a question to get an explanation for this. You can answer there, if you know the reason why it behaves like this :-)

Comment: @Christophe `var` matches the type inferred from the return value of `SomeMethod()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#var-declarations-in-case-expressions is the best doc I can find, although that's talking about switch statements.

Comment: I can't add an answer now anyway ><

Comment: @canton7 If you disagree with the question being closed, feel free to vote to re-open. (I actually voted to reopen myself, as I don't agree with this question having been closed - especially since the upvotes on this indicate that people by and large consider the question worth reading).

Comment: IMO the question is fairly specific: "Is this legal, and are there any problems with it?". While there's some opinion in the comments about whether this is a good idea, that wasn't the intention of the question.

Comment: "Is this legal" is answered by the compiler, and "are there any problems with it" is rather open-ended. How will we know when this question is answered?

Comment: The biggest problem for me is that you can't use `var`. You have to type the name. Trivial in this example, sure, but what about complex generic types (e.g. when checking the result of `FirstOrDefault()`)? And the technique is impossible with anonymous types because their names are not legal. I like the old pattern because I can use it consistently for everything.

Comment: Not so related with refactoring question. If you'll use `variableHere != null`, in terms of efficiency, Jared Parsons recommends this instead `variableHere is object`. He said it emits efficient IL. "Think developers should embrace `is object` as the canonical non-null test in C#. It works in every version, won't compile when the expression type is a struct, logical opposite of `is null`, emits efficient IL, ... the only fault you can say is the name isn't obvious." -- https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1115019017297596416

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously the 2 implementations are very similar, the difference would be negligible in *memory*, *allocations*, and *cycles*.

The compiler basically treats them as follows (for reference types)

**First**

```
MyType myType = SomeMethod();
if (myType != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myType.ToString());
}
```

**Second**

```
MyType myType2;
if ((object)(myType2 = SomeMethod()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myType2.ToString());
}
```

Probably better seen with the *IL*

**First**

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: call instance class C/MyType C::SomeMethod()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: brfalse.s IL_0015

IL_000a: ldloc.0
IL_000b: callvirt instance string[mscorlib] System.Object::ToString()
IL_0010: call void[mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

**Second**

```
IL_0015: ldarg.0
IL_0016: call instance class C/MyType C::SomeMethod()
IL_001b: dup
IL_001c: stloc.1
IL_001d: brfalse.s IL_002a

IL_001f: ldloc.1
IL_0020: callvirt instance string[mscorlib] System.Object::ToString()
IL_0025: call void[mscorlib] System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

<sub>***Note** : You can check out the disassembly, IL and jit-asm [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRWQTwHYGNXIxJQC2yANDCAJYA2APgAIAMABIwIwDcAsAFCMAzOwBMrAMKsA3v36t57YYzEBZTABVMABwhyFMvgtYBfPUaGs1mnawDKAexIQVEGAAt7AEwAUASjP6AUbsAOys2BAA7pYa2hB+vIbBpknmSgAsln5B0jkKAG5QCKxQrAC8do7Orh4+vol58tRgrN6lAIQV2HC0tP6pwbkDg/KcAJxtAHTq9rZE1NgA5n71jSayw0bNrQ5OLu5efqzUyDHWEKz5/SPyBjfmHBP507PzSyuJ9ymD3wr8xkA=)*</sub>

The *IL* difference is basically 2 opcodes:

- `dup` : Copies the current topmost value on the evaluation stack, and then pushes the copy onto the evaluation stack.
- `Ldloc` : Loads the local variable at a specific index onto the evaluation stack.

When *Jitted*, it would most likely *optimize* into the same *instructions* anyway

---

**Summary**

1. There is no appreciable technical difference.
2. Yeah the `is` version is a bit neater and a little more succinct I guess.
3. It's probably more printable characters, so if you have printable character *OCD* or suffer brutal code reviews, it might not be a good thing
4. If you like it and your team likes it, go with it.
5. It's not really my cup of tea

Comment: I wanted to know (1) and thanks for (5). If someone would show me such code in codereview/interview earlier I wouldn't guess the answer myself. So probably I'll stick to (5) too.

Answer (score 2):

I found the compiler is very intelligent.
There are several variants of translations for the `is` expression:

```
if(SomeMethod() is MyType a) {...}
```

---

1. `SomeMethod` returns `MyType`

   - `MyType` has no override operator ==, and variable `a` is not used

     ```
     if (SomeMethod() != null) {...}
     ```
   - `MyType` has override operator ==, but variable `a` is not used

     ```
     if ((object)(SomeMethod()) != null) {...}
     ```
   - `MyType` has no override operator ==, and variable `a` is used

     ```
     MyType a;
     if ((a = SomeMethod()) != null) {...}
     ```
   - `MyType` has override operator ==, and variable `a` is used

     ```
     MyType a;
     if ((object)(a = SomeMethod()) != null) {...}
     ```
2. `SomeMethod` returns other type like `object`

   - Variable `a` is not used

     ```
     if (SomeMethod() is MyType) {...}
     ```
   - `MyType` has no override operator ==, and variable `a` is used

     ```
     MyType a;
     if ((a = (SomeMethod() as MyType)) != null) {...}
     ```
   - `MyType` has override operator ==, and variable `a` is used

     ```
     MyType a;
     if ((object)(a = (SomeMethod() as MyType)) != null) {...}
     ```

BTW you can check all these variants by ILSpy or something similar.

Comment: I think you can safely assume that `a` is used, because the syntax `SomeMethod() is MyType` is legal and performs a null check -- and you used it in some of the expansions -- so declaring and not using the variable is just extra pointless code.

Comment: Sometimes you may remove some codes and leave a warning(CS0168), so this shows `is type` and `is type a` are identical when `a` is not used, and no warning ,this behaviours differently with unused local variable.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you for documenting this! This is particularly relevant when manually writing expression trees, where we do not have access `is`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use it to perform an identity cast on a reference type, as the null check is much more intuitive to the future reader.

For nullable types it's an entirely different story.  Given `struct S`, then

```
void foo(S? p)
{
    if (p is S s) {
        bar(s);
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo(S? p)
{
    if (p.HasValue) {
        bar(p.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
}
```

and avoiding the `GetValueOrDefault()` call (or worse, read of the `Value` property which does *another* null-check) is IMO very useful and significantly helps readability.

Comment: Thanks for opinion (the more people don't like it, the better). I haven't thought about value types and nullables. But does `GetValueOrDefault()` makes sense in second example? Is it code generated by compiler? After `HasValue` check I'd just use`Value` directly. Or is it due to thread-safety?

Comment: @Sinatr: Counter-intuitively, `GetValueOrDefault()` returns the internal value directly, while the `Value` property getter is more expensive.  So "use `Value` directly" is not direct at all.

Answer (score 0):

In c# 8, a sugar expression for testing not null using pattern matching expression:

```cs
if (name is {})  // name !=null
   Console.WriteLine("name is not null")
```